# arules apriori command hanging or just taking long

Tags: arules

I used apriori command from the arules package on a transaction object and one the CPU's went up to about 97% for 20 or so min. Then it went down to cycling between 0.7 % and 0.3% and has been doing that for about 24 hr. and I do not have the prompt back in RStudio; just blinking. I have 2666 transactions and 376 items. There is probably a lot similarity among some of the transactions, meaning that some transactions can share over 100 items.

This is the first time I have used this package, so I was wondering if this behavior was normal or what should I do.

I am running on CentOS 7 with 24 GB RAM and 16 CPU's, and using RStudio Server.

My command:

```
 rules <- apriori(adjacdmMtrans, parameter =list(support = 0.002, confidence=0.75))
```

Some info put out by arules after entering the above command:

```
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
       0.75    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE   0.002      1     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 5 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[376 item(s), 2666 transaction(s)] done [0.03s].
sorting and recoding items ... [376 item(s)] done [0.01s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your machine probably runs out of memory for the R process and starts swapping. In the worse case, apriori has to create for 376 items in the order of 10^12 candidates of length 4. Start with a higher support value.